# Personal Team in Xcode not granting permissions

Tags: xcode, permissions

So I'm using my account as an individual in Xcode (personal team), but for some reason, Xcode won't allow me to use features such as changing package names. The reason for this is because I don't have the proper permissions. I have no idea how to give myself the proper permissions, as it's a personal team that I'm basically locked out of.

Edit: I hear something about deleting the developer keychain? How would I do that?

Comment: Show screenshots or describe in more detail exactly what's happening and the error messages you get.

Comment: @sschale http://tinypic.com/r/kbahvm/9

From what I've seen, it's a common error that has to do with not enough permissions. But I'm an Indie developer, which is why it's really weird